# Esp8266-01 module attached to Arduino resets when DC motor runs

Tags: arduino, dc-motor, esp8266

```
Machifit JT80SL DC 3-6V Water Pump: 3-6v 
Servo sg90: 3-7.2v
Esp 8266 01: 3.3v
```

I have 2 Arduino Uno both has their own ac-dc power adapter. 
Lets say, 1st Arduino is `Ard1` and 2nd is `Ard2`.

The `Ard1` communicates to a web server (BLYNK) with Esp 01.

Using I2C, `Ard1` sends command to `Ard2` to power/move the DC motor/Servo.

So far, **it has no problem operating with Servo**. But,

Whenever the `Ard1` commands the `Ard2` to power the DC motor.

Right when the DC motor runs(using `digitalWrite(motor,HIGH)`) the Esp 01 resets.

---

- Tried using `analogWrite(motor, 102)` though it won't reset instantly, prolong usage randomly resets it anytime.
- I also tried to test operating Servo and DC motor simultaneously in `Ard2` using Serial commands, without I2C/Esp01. There was no problem at all, both works flawlessly.

Please, pardon me for the poor presentation. I have no solid knowledge on 
electronics/electrical.

Below is the diagram of the wiring. 
[image]

Comment: The RX input to the ESP-01 is a 3.3V input. You should not be driving it directly from the 5V output of an Arduino.

Comment: I didn't knew rx pin also has voltage input, thanks alot.

Answer (score 0):

I resorted to a 9v battery supply for dc however problem still exist but not that severe, it still cuts the connection. Finally, my latest solution was attaching a 10ko resistor between esp's ch_d to 3.3v of arduino and 1k between gnd and esp's rx and another 1k between esp's rx to arduino's. So far everything went well.